# sin function in numpy have value greater than 1

Tags: numpy

In numpy `np.sin()` function is used to generate sine function, it generates values greater than 1. But the sine function should generate output in the range (-1 to +1).

```
>>> np.sin(np.pi/2)
1.0
>>> np.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> np.pi/2
1.5707963267948966
>>> np.sin(1.57)
0.9999996829318346
>>> np.sin(2*np.pi)
-2.4492935982947064e-16
>>> np.sin(np.pi)
1.22464679914735
```

Comment: Can you check your result again? I think you accidentally copied only part of the output or something.  For the last one you are missing the multiple `10^-16`.

Answer (score 0):

You've mis-copied the last line. The correct output is

```
>>> np.sin(np.pi)
1.2246467991473532e-16
```

That's 1.22e-16, so approximately, well, 0.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean something like

```
>>> np.sin(np.pi)
1.2246467991473532e-16
```

The output is not greater than 1. In fact, it is very small. The `e-16` represents x10^-16 (ten to the power of minus sixteen). This is a common notation, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation